# Shadcn UI installation breaks Tailwind CSS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Shadcn UI (https://ui.shadcn.com/) was working fine until I just for a couple weeks until yesterday, when I ran my NextJS app in my local host and none of the tailwind was working. To debug the issue, I created a blank NextJS 13 app in a completely new file location, and everything worked fine; tailwind was working on the default nextJS 13 page. I then ran

```
npx shadcn-ui init
```

without installing any of the components. Which did not spit out any errors, but then none of the tailwind styling worked anymore.

my tailwind.config.js after instillation:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        border: "hsl(var(--border))",
        input: "hsl(var(--input))",
        ring: "hsl(var(--ring))",
        background: "hsl(var(--background))",
        foreground: "hsl(var(--foreground))",
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--primary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--primary-foreground))",
        },
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--secondary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))",
        },
        destructive: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--destructive))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))",
        },
        muted: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--muted))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--muted-foreground))",
        },
        accent: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--accent))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--accent-foreground))",
        },
        popover: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--popover))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--popover-foreground))",
        },
        card: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--card))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--card-foreground))",
        },
      },
      borderRadius: {
        lg: "var(--radius)",
        md: "calc(var(--radius) - 2px)",
        sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
      },
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: 0 },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: 0 },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
}
```

my utils.ts after instillation

```
import { ClassValue, clsx } from "clsx"
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge"
 
export function cn(...inputs: ClassValue[]) {
  return twMerge(clsx(inputs))
}
```

[the default page after instillation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta8jG.png)

EDIT: after some testing, the issue seems to be coming from the globals.css and tailwind.config.js, still not sure what about them though.

Comment: I think you would want this `import { clsx, type ClassValue } from "clsx"` in your utils.ts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my case the Shadcn components did not find the styles exported by tailwind.
As answered by @moyindavid the problem is in tailwind.config.

Solution:
Add the '@' folder to the exports of the tailwind attributes.

```
module.exports = {
   darkMode: ["class"],
   content: [
     './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
     './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
     './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
     './@/**/*.{ts,tsx}', // <- HERE
     ],
```

Answer (score 5):

If your case is similar to mine and you used the src folder to wrap the app folder, the problem comes from the tailwind config file.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    ],
```

This is what you have. However, the content maps to the wrong directories.
Update the strings in the content array using this.

```
content: [
    './src/app/**/*.{ts,tsx}', './src/components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar problem, where my form inputs started behaving in a weird way after the shadcn installation. The problem is that the installation overrides the plugins array, on the tailwind configuration file, and in my case, removed the @tailwindcss/forms.
So, writing it back solved the problem. In *tailwind.config.js*:

```
module.exports = {
...
plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/forms"), require("tailwindcss-animate")],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it broke Tailwind dark mode. I bring back by simply changing `darkMode` property to `media` instead of `class`.

[Official Documentation:](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode)

> If you want to support toggling dark mode manually instead of relying
> on the operating system preference, use the class strategy instead of
> the media strategy

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem multiple times.
`npx shadcn-ui init` will overwrite your `tailwind.config.js`
So remember to backup your previous settings and then merge it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I have found for this is because sometimes when you run

```
npx shadcn-ui@latest init
```

command, it might override your glabal css - check to make sure your previous rules are persisted

Also check the tailwind.config.ts file to make settings are persisted especially the
theme.extend.colors  - this might be completely overwritten.
Always a good idea to commit prior to making major changes to existing projects that way you can have a reference.